# c++ ffmpeg: always the same frame?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I have a code, that (should) give me another frame for each call using ffmpeg. My problem is, that it is always the same frame, that I decode...

Could someone tell me, what I´m missing here?

```
bool nextFrameFound = false;
while(!nextFrameFound)
{
    AVPacket pkt;

    int err = av_read_frame(ctx, &pkt);
    if (err < 0)
    {
        break;
        system("Pause");
        exit(2);
    }

    if (pkt.stream_index == strm)
    {
        int got = 0;
        AVFrame * frame = av_frame_alloc();
        int videoFrameBytes = avcodec_decode_video2(codecCtx, frame, &got, &pkt);

        if (got)
        {
            AVFrame * rgbFrame = av_frame_alloc();

            avpicture_alloc((AVPicture *)rgbFrame, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, codecCtx->width, codecCtx->height);
            sws_scale(swCtx, frame->data, frame->linesize, 0, frame->height, rgbFrame->data, rgbFrame->linesize);

            for (int i = 0; i < codecCtx->height; i++)
            {
                char * data = (char*)rgbFrame->data[0] + i*rgbFrame->linesize[0];
                //process data

            }
            nextFrameFound = true;
            avcodec_close(codecCtx);

        }

        av_free_packet(&pkt);
    }
}
avformat_network_deinit();
```

I guess, it is a missunderstanding in using ffmpeg but I can't help myself :(

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If it's always frame, it should be inside the for loop... You sure you want to access `rgbFrame->data[0]` ever time?

Comment: I think, that rgbFrame is only on frame of my video and not a video sequence

Comment: All other data entries are zero so that wasn't the problem

Comment: It's not clear what do you ask for...  This code snippet always process only the first decoded frame. What do you mean by saying *each call using ffmpeg*?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

I'm not allowed to delete the package after finishing the frame.
Instead I have to delete it after I'm done with my video.

Thanks for guessing with me!